# Reading toolpart property value

Tags: 2010

I have a webpart with a toolpart class. The toolpart renders fine, but how do I read/"get" the toolpart's value from the webpart class? ie if a button is pressed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If its a custom ToolPart property you can check this MSDN link that is explaining you how to get toolpart values within a webpart

[Getting custompropertytoolpart in a webpart](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.webpartpages.custompropertytoolpart.aspx)

**EDIT**

This link is more relevant to your question

[MSDN getting/Updating toolpart class properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd584178%28v=office.11%29.aspx)

> To obtain a reference to the Web Part to update its properties, the
>   ToolPart class has an accessor property called ParentToolPane that
>   returns a reference to the ToolPane object. The ToolPane object is the
>   class that keeps track of which Web Part is selected, and in turn, it
>   has an accessor property called SelectedWebPart that returns a WebPart
>   object for the current Web Part.

Hope it helps :)